# Почему мой TCP сервер на Delphi, грузит процессор 10% на клиента

Tags: delphi

Решил написать, многопоточный сервер, на IdTcpServer. Чтобы получить многопоточность, я из OnExecute вызываю функцию, а из нее другую, в зависимости от запроса, передаю в качестве параметров записи типа record, которые состоят из параметров String, Integer, Array [...] of String/Integer.

При запуске приложения ЦП = 0%, память 1.9 мб, после подключения ЦП = 6-11%, память 2.2мб, второе подключение ЦП = 18-22%, память 2.4 мб

Насколько я знаю все должно укладываться в 1%, подскажите что я не так делаю, в какую сторону копать?

Тут показано как я построил проект

Unit1.pas

```
unit Unit1;

implementation

uses myTypes, Unit2;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Request : String;
  GetRespons: RGetRespons;
  Respons : ZRespons;
begin
  Respons := GetRespons.ResponsCreate(Request);
end;
end.
```

Unit2.pas

```
unit Unit2;

uses myTypes;

type
  RGetRespons = record
    function ResponsCreate(Request: String): ZRespons;
  private
    function RequestPars(Request: String): ZParsedRequest;
  end; 

implementation

uses Unit3;

function RGetRespons.ResponsCreate(Request: String): ZRespons;
var
  ParsedRequest: ZParsedRequest;
  iParam1: String;
  iParam2: Integer;
  Calculate: RCalculate;
begin
  ParsedRequest := RequestPars(Request);  
  if ParsedRequest.Param1 then
  begin
    iParam1 := Calculate.NewFunc(ParsedRequest);
    iParam2 := 
  end;   
  Result.Param1 := iParam1;
  Result.Param2 := iParam2;
end;

function RGetRespons.RequestPars(Request: String): ZParsedRequest;
begin
  Result.Param1 := Value1;
  Result.Param2 := Value2;
  Result.Param3 := Value3;
end;
end.
```

Unit3.pas

```
unit Unit3;

uses myTypes;

type
  RCalculate = record
    function NewFunc(ParsedRequest: ZParsedRequest;): String;
  end;

implementation

uses Unit4, Unit5;

function RCalculate.NewFunc(ParsedRequest: ZParsedRequest;): String; 
var
  ReadDB: RReadDB;
  UpdateDB: RUpdateDB;
  iParam: String;
begin
  iParam := ReadDB.Read(ParsedRequest.Param2)
  ...
  UpdateDB.Update(ParsedRequest.Param2, iParam);
  Result := iParam;
end;  
end.
```

Unit4.pas

```
unit Unit4; 

uses myTypes;

type
  RReadDB = record
    function Read(Name: String): String;
  end; 

implementation

uses Unit1; 

function RReadDB.Read(Name: String): String;
begin
  Form1.FDQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` = "' + Name + '" LIMIT 1 LOCK IN SHARE MODE');
  Result := Form1.FDQuery1.FieldByName('col1').AsString;
end;
end.
```

Unit5.pas

```
unit Unit5; 

uses myTypes;

type
  RUpdateDB = record
    function Update(Name, Value: String): Boolean;
  end; 

implementation

uses Unit1;

function RUpdateDB.Update(Name, Value: String): Boolean;
begin      
  Form1.FDQuery1.SQL.Add('UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY `table` SET'
        + ' `col1` = "' + Value + '"'
        + ' WHERE `name` = "' + Name + '" LIMIT 1');
  Result := True;
end;
end.
```

myTypes.pas

```
unit myTypes;

type
  ZRespons = record
    Param1: String;
    Param2: Integer;
  end;

type
  ZParsedRequest = record
    Param1: Boolean;
    Param2: String;
    Param3: Array [0..5] of String;
  end;

implementation
end.
```

**UPD**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

создал новый проект, в котором, в таймере каждые 10 миллисекунд читаю самую большую таблицу(7x100 varchar в основном), как у себя в проекте, ЦП от 0.2 до 1.4% минуты 3 никаких ошибок не было, может дело и не в базе вовсе?

Comment: 10%? а сколько ядер? может 8? и может тогда на 12.5% загружает CPU? это значит что 100% загрузки на 1 ядре

Comment: да он 8 ядерный, а что это меняет?

Comment: это значит что 100% загрузки на 1 ядре. если удалить все операции с базой данных, ситуация меняется?

Comment: чтобы быстро понять, проблема в запросах (операциях с базой) или нет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58930/discussion-between-artgrek13-and-zam).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда то я нашел код для приема и передачи сообщений по TCP

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  ReqStrem : TMemoryStream;
  ReqData  : TIdBytes;
  ReqString : String;
  ResString: String;
begin
//
  if AContext.Connection.Connected then
  begin
    try
      if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size > 0 then
      begin
        ReqStrem := TMemoryStream.Create;
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(ReqStrem,
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size, false);
        ReqStrem.Position := 0;
        ReadTIdBytesFromStream(ReqStrem, ReqData, ReqStrem.Size);
        ReqStrem.Free;
        ReqString := BytesToString(ReqData, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
        ResString := RGetTCPRespons.TcpResCreate(ReqString);
        try
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferOpen;
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(ResString + #0);
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferFlush;
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferClear;
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferClose;
        except

        end;
      end;
    finally
      sleep(10);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

И все время я задавался вопросом, зачем нужен **sleep(10);**? ну и неделю назад удалил его из проекта(

Вот отсюда и бралась нагрузка на проц, сейчас 0.1-0.2%

В общем, я где то вычитал, если есть действия которые многократно повторяются, потоки, while, repeat, for,  в них нужно вставлять sleep() или какой нибудь аналог, я не знаю, что еще бывает.