# Как правильно создать функцию Delphi

Tags: delphi, функции

Я хочу написать 10 функций в отдельном .pas файле, а потом вызывать их по мере необходимости. Делаю так:

```
unit Unit5;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, myTypes;

type
  RGetInfo = record
    function GetGroups(ClientName: String): XGroups;
    function GetLanguages(ClientName: String): XLanguages;
    function GetSettings(ClientName: String): XSettings;
  end;

implementation

...
end.
```

Вызываю так:

```
var
  GetInfo: RGetInfo;
  Groups: XGroups;
begin
  Groups := GetInfo.GetGroups('Client1');
```

Может есть, более грамотный, способ? Например вместо record.

Comment: Может быть попробовать класс? Он, собственно, предназначен для этого. Создаете класс в `interface`-секции в отдельном юните, внутри класса объявляете N нужных вам функций или процедур, в `implementation` реализуете. Потом создаёте экземпляр класса, и вызываете нужную функцию. Можно объявить эти функции классовыми (`class function MyFunction(...)`), тогда и создавать экземпляр класса не нужно, можно так: `TMyClass.MyFunction(...)`.

Comment: @BlackWitcher а `record` не предназначен?

Comment: ваш вариант реализации оптимален, за исключением того, что методы следует объявить _классовыми_ (`class function`)и использовать не через переменную, а через имя класса `RGetIfno.GetfGroups`. _зы: общепринято, за некоторыми исключениями, конечно, начинать имена класса в приефикса `T`_

Comment: то что вы предлагаете, не тоже самое что и в ответе @Igor? или я не правильно понял?

Comment: @teran, в `Record` _можно_ так сделать, как делал автор вопроса, но вообще задачи `Record` всё же несколько иные. [Описание по-русски](http://www.delphibasics.ru/Record.php), [официальная документация](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)), где английским по белому говорится, что рекорд — аналог структуры в других языках программирования, со всеми вытекающими (основное назначение - данные, а не методы их обработки всё же).

Comment: @BlackWitcher с тех пор как в рекорды внесли методы и конструкторы их предназначение несколько поменялось. В справке вы даже можете найти раздел "Record" и "Advanced records". Так что рассматривать можно в виде более легковесной замены классам, особенно при решении задачи простой логической группировки методов.

Comment: @teran, я вовсе и не спорю с вашими утверждениями, что можно, и вовсе не говорю, что нельзя. Просто, как я уже говорил в другом комментарии, мне кажется более семантически верным использование класса, и только. По мне - так еще со времен самых первых версий Delphi было вполне логичное разбиение - записи - для хранения данных, классы - для работы с ними. Разумеется, сейчас методы можно использовать и в рекордах, и от этого будет польза, так что в данном случае, да - эффективнее использовать именно записи.

Comment: то есть, сейчас вы говорите, что как было, с записями, было лучше, потому что быстрее работает?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 нет, для статических методов разницы в быстродействии нет

Comment: ладно уже оставлю через класс, тем боле я планирую реализовывать в дальнейшем наследование, я все это перепроверяю потому что процессор грузится, может подскажете что нибудь? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667357/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-tcp-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-delphi-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80-10-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667480/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-delphi-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b9-mysql-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Статические методы класса:

```
RGetInfo = class
public
  class function GetGroups(ClientName: String): XGroups;
  class function GetLanguages(ClientName: String): XLanguages;
  class function GetSettings(ClientName: String): XSettings;
end;

var
  Groups: XGroups;
begin
  Groups := RGetInfo.GetGroups('Client1');
```

или просто отдельные функции:

```
interface

  function GetGroups(ClientName: String): XGroups;
  function GetLanguages(ClientName: String): XLanguages;
  function GetSettings(ClientName: String): XSettings;

implementation

function GetGroups(ClientName: String): XGroups;
begin
  result := ...
end;


var
  Groups: XGroups;
begin
  Groups := GetGroups('Client1');
```

Comment: никаких конструкторов больше не надо? вместо record class и обращаться через R?

Comment: отдельные функции после implementation без объявления?

Comment: Да, смотрите ответ.

Comment: а в чем отличие первого варианта от второго, как определиться какой выбрать?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 Выбирайте первый вариант - он группирует функции в отдельный класс, это и логически хорошо, когда в файле много функций, и уменьшает вероятность конфликта имен - название `GetGroups` уж больно общо.

Comment: спасибо!.......

Comment: а чем собственно класс лучше записи то?

Comment: Я не знаю, мне нравится тем что в var не надо постоянно об]являть. Но у меня ошибка This form of method call only allowed for class methods or constructor

Comment: @ArtGrek13 Вы не написали слово `class` перед словом `function`.

Comment: я и не заметил. )

Comment: @ArtGrek13 аналогично если напишите `class` для методов вашей записи,то можно будет вызывать таким же образом. Использование классов для данной задачи это перебор. Нет смысла объявлять класс, если все равно все вызов статические, отсутствует наследование, и т.п.. На записях построена довольная большая часть RTL, взять хотя бы `IOUtils` с его `TDirectory, TPath, TFile` или `TRttiContext`. При таком использовании все отличия классов от записей исчезают, поэтому  и нет смысла в их использовании.

Comment: @teran Я только учусь поэтому нет наследований, налажу это, потом улучшу. " если все равно все вызов статические" вызов из другого юнита тоже считается статическим?

Comment: @ArtGrek13, статический - значит постоянный, из какого юнита не вызывай.

Comment: @teran, класс не лучше записей (record) и не хуже. Это иное просто. Прежде всего - record - это значимый тип, т.е. работа с ним осуществляется по значению. Класс - ссылочный тип, работа с ним ведется по ссылкам, а не по значению. Подробнее можно посмотреть тут ([англ. SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424868/why-should-we-use-classes-rather-than-records-or-vice-versa)), или, например, [тут](http://www.vr-online.ru/content/kogda-vygodno-ispolzovat-record-vmesto-class-1209)

Comment: @BlackWitcher когда мы работаем со статическими методами, нам вообще без разницы значимый это тип или ссылочный. Мой комментарий про "лучше-хуже" написан не к тому чтобы спросить в чем разница между структурами и классами.  Автор ответа усложняет вариант Авторов вопроса, предлагая использовать более "тяжеловесную" структуру.  При этом момент использования записей он обошел стороной. Комментарий мой для намека, что ответ следует расширить. К такому ответу я не могу поставить плюс, ибо считаю его не полным, и упускающим самую суть. Какой то бездумный переход на классы и все. Никакой аргументации

Comment: @teran, вот теперь понял, что вы имели ввиду. А вообще - структура (запись) хранится в стеке и потому быстрее, чем класс, который хранится в куче. Не уверен на 100% (а всего лишь на 95%), что даже если мы объявим методы класса статическими (классовыми), то они всё равно будут храниться в куче, т.к. если для статического вызова мы не вызываем конструктор класса в коде, это вовсе не значит, что конструктор класса не вызывается компилятором, просто, насколько я помню, он вызывается неявно и единожды, и экземпляр такого класса жив, пока жива программа. Но живет оно в куче (heap).

Comment: А использовать класс в данном вопросе было бы вернее исключительно семантически, так как структура в первую очередь предполагает хранение данных, а задача класса - _действия_ над данными. Функции - есть действия. Но опять же, если посмотреть в сторону VCL и какого-нибудь модуля, например, `IOUtils`, то можно [увидеть](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory), что используется для таких сущностей как `TFile`, `TDirectory`, `TPath` - это `record`.

Comment: @BlackWitcher в стеке и куче хранятся данные, к методам это не относится. Для классов и записей разница в методах в том, что у первых есть еще таблица дополнительная виртуальных методов появляющаяся при наследовании и их перекрытии.  Конструктор класса может быть вызван только явным образом. Неявно вызываться может лишь классовый конструктор, если таковой объявлен (`class constructor Create()`), и вызывается он при первом упоминании имени класс/записи в коде.

Comment: кстати говоря, статические методы это `static` а классовые это `class`. и между ними есть разница