# Как в Delphi работать с базой MySQL не нагружая процессор?

Tags: mysql, delphi

Мой сервер сильно грузит процессор и при подключении второго клиента вылетает ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На форме:

```
FDConnection1: TFDConnection;
FDQuery1: TFDQuery;
FDGUIxWaitCursor1: TFDGUIxWaitCursor;
FDPhysMySQLDriverLink1: TFDPhysMySQLDriverLink;
```

Процесс такой:

Одна функция вызывает по очереди 5-10 раз функции с таким содержанием

```
  Form1.FDQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  Form1.FDQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `client` = "' + Client + '" LIMIT 1');
  Form1.FDQuery1.Open;
    Result.values[0] := Form1.FDQuery1.FieldByName('value1').AsString;
    Result.values[1] := Form1.FDQuery1.FieldByName('value2').AsString;
    Result.values[2] := Form1.FDQuery1.FieldByName('value3').AsString;
    Result.values[3] := Form1.FDQuery1.FieldByName('value4').AsString;
```

Потом, выполняются расчеты, и результаты сохраняются, в соответствующие таблицы, так же вызовом 5-10 функций типа:

```
  Form1.FDQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  Form1.FDQuery1.SQL.Add('UPDATE `Table` SET'
    + ' `value1` = "' + values[0] + '",'
    + ' `value2` = "' + values[1] + '",'
    + ' `value3` = "' + values[2] + '",'
    + ' `value4` = "' + values[3] + '"'
    + ' WHERE `client` = "' + Client + '" LIMIT 1');
  Form1.FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Таблицы разные, одна нужна полностью, из другой пару строк, с третьей одну строку.

Что я делаю не так? Почему грузится проц и вылетает ошибка при подключении других клиентов?

Пробовал добавлять в запросы SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE, UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY,  не помогло

**UPD**

убрал вызов функции из условия **if**, ошибка перестала вылетать при подключении нового клиента, но проц грузится по прежнему, при одном подключенном клиенте примерно 10%, что это может быть!?

**UPD**

создал в ручную 35 пар Connection Query, у каждого кваери прописал свой конекшн, в остальном свойства идентичны, копипастил. В каждой функцие идет обращение к своей паре. никаких изменений, два клиента работают минуты 2-3 и ошибка как в вопросе, проц грузится также, не меньше, рам увеличился

Comment: Open - вижу. А Close есть?

Comment: да, был, удалил только что, посмотреть вдруг что поменяется, сейчас верну на место, кстати после ExecSQL тоже должен быть?

Comment: Сервер ведь Indy, правильно? А все запросы в сервере идут именно в таком виде - `Form1.FDQueryX.yyy`?

Comment: Каждому Open-у нужно дать по Close :). ExecSQL не нуждается в этом. Но больше меня интересует второй вопрос, про indy и запросы.

Comment: да, IdTcpServer из события OnExecute вызываю функцию которая потом выполняет выше описаное

Comment: вернее между OnExecute и выше указаным 3-4 функции

Comment: Вы в курсе, что OnExecute совершается в дополнительном потоке? Для начала - попробуйте обернуть весь код работы с БД (и если есть - с визуальными компонентами), который выполняется в OnExecute - в TThread,Synchronize. Но это будет не очень хорошо (как минимум - скорость обработки запросов упадет), хотя должно помочь. А вообще - ваш вопрос нуждается в ответе а-ля"как правильно работать в многопоточном режиме".

Comment: визуальных компонент нет, если я правильно понимаю что это). есть IdTcpServer, HttpServer и то что я описал выше. про то что OnExecute для каждого клиента в отдельном потоке знаю, в этом и задумка, вызываю ряд функций, получается многопоточный сервер, на большее я пока не способен, а чем это не подходит для баз данных? поясните пожалуста, я не понял

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58936/discussion-between-artgrek13-and-kami).

Comment: Создавайте TFDConnection и FDQuery динамически для каждого клиента и проблема решится.

Comment: Я тему другую создавал, у меня по мимо того что слетает база при втором и более подключениях, еще и сильно процессор грузится, и я думаю все дело именно в базе, если я создам еще экземпляр для ругого подключения это не увеличит загрузку ЦП?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667357/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-tcp-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-delphi-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80-10-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Почитайте про работу с БД в мнопоточном режиме и многое станет понятно.

Comment: как же трудно, найти дельную статью в интернете!( прочел http://www.delphi-manual.ru/synchronize.php, получается мне нужно обернуть в Synchronize() именно вызов функции где происходит обращение к бд? то есть я из OnExecut вызываю функцию, из нее другую из нее третью и когда дело доходит до вызова функции где происходит чтение из бд я эту функцию должен обернуть в Synchronize(),

Comment: Я бы создавал отдельные экземпляры компонентов для работы с бд при каждом вызове функции и тогда не нужно ничего заворачивать в Synchronize. Вы посмотрите не то, как использовать Syncronize, а как работать с БД из нескольких потоков.

Comment: процессор не умрет? как я писал выше он грузится сильно, на одно подключение примерно 10%

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667357/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-tcp-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-delphi-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80-10-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58937/discussion-between-artgrek13-and--).

Comment: @kami Вы говорили "Вы в курсе, что OnExecute совершается в дополнительном потоке", подскажите, на одно соединение, идет 1 поток? Пока не выполнится код в OnExecute, второй экземпляр, с того же соединения, не может запуститься, верно?

Comment: 1 - да. У Indy одно соединение - один поток.  2 - тоже да, если я правильно понял: вложенности вызовов OnExecute в рамках одного потока не будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в отсутствии sleep()  в событии IdTcpServer.OnExecute,

циклы и потоки грузят процессор

Comment: Я бы сказал неграмотно написанный код в циклах и потоках грузят процессор.

Comment: @androschuk а разве можно грамотно написать код в OnExecute  не добавляя sleep и что бы не грузило сервер, при условии что клиент сервер не будут отсоединяться после каждого сообщения